# How to convert object to array only if its each value is true

Tags: javascript

I have selectedSizeList on my state.

```
selectedSizeList = {1: false, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: false}
```

How do I convert my selectedSizeList to this array?

[2, 3, 4]

Do I have better algorithm than this one? (I assume my solution is not correct)

```
let array = [];
Objects.keys(selectedSizeList).maps((item) => {
    if(item.value) array.push(item.value)
);
return array;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#filter` to filter out all keys with `true` value.

```js
const selectedSizeList = {1: false, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: false};
const result = Object
                 .keys(selectedSizeList)
                 .filter(k => selectedSizeList[k])
                 .map(Number);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all get the array keys using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter only the `true` values like this.

```js
var selectedSizeList = {1: false, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: false};

var keys = Object.keys(selectedSizeList);

var filtered = keys.filter(function(key) {
    return selectedSizeList[key]
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (O(n) solution):

```js
selectedSizeList = {1: false, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: false};

var arr = [];
for (var key in selectedSizeList) {
    if(selectedSizeList[key]){
       arr.push(key);
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to return an`array that you can then use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on to return a new array.

```js
selectedSizeList = {1: false, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: false};
let array = Object.keys(selectedSizeList).filter((item) => {
 if(selectedSizeList[item]) return item;
  });
  //returns [2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.keys to get an array that you can then filter for values equal to true which will return an array of numbers as a string. You can then map through the array using Number to convert the number strings to numbers which may or may not be necessary depending on what you plan to do with this result. I put this into a function that you can re-use or at least not have your object hard coded with.

```js
var selectedSizeList = {1: false, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: false};

// Re-usable function not tied to specific object
const filterForTrueValue = (obj) => Object
                                      .keys(obj)
                                      .filter(k => obj[k])
                                      .map(Number);

console.log(filterForTrueValue(selectedSizeList));
```